# How to specify `buildPythonPackage` wheel Python versions, ABI, and platform tags?

Tags: nix

When using [`buildPythonPackage`](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/vcard/-/blob/3939f33e0201f11dd40a1c830ccb7c49356aaafe/derivation.nix#L30/derivation.nix) the resulting wheel ends up as `$dist/${pname}-${version}-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. `py2.py3` are the Python versions, `none` is the ABI, and `any` is the platform. **How do I specify these when building the package?** The closest thing to a reference I could find in `nixpkgs/pkgs/development/interpreters/python` was `computeWheelUrl`, which takes `python ? "py2.py3"`, `abi ? "none"`, and `platform ? "any"`.

Answer (score -1):

See the relevant PEP specifying the wheel format:
https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention

These attributes need to be passed on to the fetcher, `fetchPypi`. The following expression shows partially how to build numpy using a pre-built wheel:

```
{ buildPythonPackage
, fetchPypi
, ...
}:

buildPythonPackage {
  pname = "numpy";
  version = "1.23.3";
  format = "wheel";
  src = fetchPypi {
    inherit pname version format;
    python = "cp310";
    abi = "cp310";
    platform = "manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64";
    sha256 = "004f0efcb2fe1c0bd6ae1fcfc69cc8b6bf2407e0f18be308612007a0762b4089";
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's not an answer. I'm already aware of the filename structure, I'm looking for how to tell `buildPythonPackage` about those parts of the filename.

Comment: Still not an answer. I'm building my own package, so I'm not using `fetchPypi`. Its arguments aren't relevant for what I'm doing.